# Is a "delayed reference" a known programming pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, delay, midi, delayed-execution

I'm trying to understand JZZ's API.

One of the pecularities is after you obtain a port (a place to send MIDI instructions to), you can do this:

```
const a = port.noteOn(0, 'C5', 127); // plays note immediately, a is Promise that returns port
const b = port.wait(500); // b is a Promise that returns an object like port

port.noteOn(0, 'E5', 127); // plays note immediately
b.noteOn(0, 'G5', 127); // plays note in 500ms
```

The [documentation](https://jazz-soft.net/doc/JZZ/common.html#wait) says:

> wait()

> `object.wait(delay)` - returns a "delayed reference" of the object.

> delay is the timeout in microseconds.

Is this "delayed reference" a known programming pattern? I haven't come across it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises

Comment: No - this uses promises as well, but you can do this: `port.wait(500).noteOn(...)` which will do the note in 500ms, even without waiting for the promise to resolve. This has the same effect: `await port.wait(500); port.noteOn(...)`

Answer (score 2):

There is no strict definition of a programming pattern, so something is a programming pattern as soon as someone declares it to be one.

Therefore, I guess all that the documentation was trying to tell was that the class for these ports encapsulates a delay (hence, the quotes). Encapsulating a delay *is* a common pattern.